# Error when installing scikit-learn library

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install scikit-learn using pip but every time I am getting error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError:
[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\aa-minhaj\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll'
Check the permissions.
```

I have tried many variations, including pip3. Also, I am not using anaconda distribution.

I checked other answers but most of them are related to Environment error, but this is an OS Error apparently.

Comment: Try running the install command from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: @KannanSuresh is their any other way ... because, this is my work laptop, for which I don't have administration credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that didn't required any admin previledges. It was as simple as to create a new virtual environment in which I installed scikit-learn library, ofcourse after re-installing my jupyterlab in the new virtual environment. Closing the issue now. Thanks